# Multiple async request

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, request

Well,here i m triyng to make some validation in a list of objects, but the function validation calls three async methods (which make requests to a database).But when i call then in paralel, the aplication gives the error 500.

```
_.each(titlesToSave, function(title, index) {
    titleValidator.validateAsync(title, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            invalidTitles.push({index: index, error: err});
        }
        joinArray[index](); 
     }); 
});

var validateAsync = function (title, next) {
    async.parallel([
        function(callback){ checkCity(title.carrier.address, callback)},
        function(callback){ checkCity(title.beneficiary.address, callback)},
        function(callback){ checkCity(title.seller.address, callback)}
    ],
        function (err,results) {
            if(err){
                console.log('ERROR: ' +err);
                next(err);
            }else{
                console.log('Result: '+results);
                next();
            }
        });
};

var checkCity = function(adress, callback){
    var url = 'http://localhost:9000/api/city/'+adress.state+'/'+adress.city;
    if (adress) {
        http.get(url, function (res) {
            console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                if (res.statusCode === 200) {
                    console.log(''+chunk);
                    callback(null, chunk);
                } else {
                    console.log('Invalid city: '+adress.city+', StatusCode: ' + res.statusCode);
                    callback(new Error('Invalid adress.'));
                }
            });
        }).on('error', function (error) {
            callback(error);
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: What is in the server error log?

Comment: You really should not do your callbacks in your `data` event handler since `data` can be emitted multiple times. Put that code in a `res.on('end', ...)` handler instead.

Comment: The res.statusCode = 500 for the 3 functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
async.eachSeries(titlesToSave, function (title, index, next) {
  titleValidator.validateAsync(title, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      invalidTitles.push({index: index, error: err});
    }

    joinArray[index]();

    next(null);
  }); 
}, function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```